# Can't extract the price variable from this website? (suspect span within a span in the codes)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have tried several ways but it usually ends up with blank or N/A only.

```
library('rvest')
library(stringr)

url <- 'https://www.kimovil.com/en/compare-smartphones/f_min_dm+unveileddate.3,i_b+slug.samsung'
webpage <- read_html(url)
device_cost_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.price')
device_cost <- html_text(device_cost_html)
device_cost <- as.numeric(device_cost)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a static webpage that can be scraped with `rvest`. The `span` elements actually *are* empty on the requested html document. What happens in your web browser is that when the html document is loaded, the browser reads the javascript code on the page, which generates further requests to the server. These requests return the actual data in json format, which the javascript code then uses to populate the empty `span` elements.

The reason why this doesn't work in `rvest` is that it has no facility to run the javascript on the page. It just returns the original empty html spans.

However, all is not lost. Using the console in your browser's developer tools, you can find the url of the json that contains the data and just request that directly. In your case, this is surprisingly straightforward:

```r
json <- httr::GET("https://www.kimovil.com/uploads/last_prefetch.json")
all_phones <- httr::content(json, "parsed")
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_phones$smartphones, function(x) {
         data.frame(name = x$full_name, price_usd = paste("$", x$usd))}))

head(df)
#>                      name price_usd
#> 1         Realme GT Neo 2     $ 489
#> 2          Google Pixel 6     $ 754
#> 3             OnePlus 9RT     $ 577
#> 4      Google Pixel 6 Pro    $ 1044
#> 5 Apple iPhone 13 Pro Max    $ 1432
#> 6     Apple iPhone 13 Pro      $ 31
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>